# JMESPath --query filter for an unusual array (dictionary), anyone up for a challenge?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-rest-api, jmespath

As you can see the picture below. I want to filter `descriptor` value where `subjectkind` is `group`. The azure CLI command I am using to get the descriptor is

```bash
az devops security group membership list --id $var1 --org https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/ --query "*.descriptor" --output tsv
```

It gives me the output but I am not able to filter the output based on the condition in the JMESPath query to get get the desired output.

FYI: I am using Windows PowerShell ISE

This is not a normal array of dictionary, here you can see the sub properties have same Key value pairs but the top node is different.

[image]

```
C:\Windows\system32> az devops security group membership list --id $var1 --org https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/

    enter code here
{
  "aad.MDQwNjg0MDMtOWYwOC03OTM": {
    "descriptor": "aad.MDQwNjg0MDMtOWYwOC03OTM",
    "directoryAlias": "JoMarie.Jumbo",
    "displayName": "Jo Marie Jumbo",
    "domain": "78b2bd11",
    "legacyDescriptor": null,
    "mailAddress": "JoMarie.Jumbo@me.nz",
    "metaType": "member",
    "origin": "aad",
    "originId": "561b354c-527b-48ae",
    "principalName": "JoMarie.Jumbo@me.nz",
    "subjectKind": "user",
    "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/mbie-sandbox/_apis/Graph/Users/aad.MDQwNjg0MDMtOWYwOC03OTM"
  },
  "aad.ZDJmMzI2ZDItOGM1ZS03NjQyLWExN2": {
    "descriptor": "aad.ZDJmMzI2ZDItOGM1ZS03NjQyLWExN2ItOWQ",
    "directoryAlias": "Paul.Jumbo",
    "displayName": "Paul Jumbo",
    "domain": "78b2bd11",
    "legacyDescriptor": null,
    "mailAddress": "Paul.Jumbo@me.nz",
    "origin": "aad",
    "originId": "67c2bda2-b9ad-4843",
    "principalName": "Paul.Jumbo@me.nz",
    "subjectKind": "user",
    "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/mbie-sandbox/_apis/Graph/Users/aad.ZDJmMzI2ZDItOGM1ZS03NjQyLWExN"
  },
  "aad.ZWUwODZlZTQtN2U3MC03M2U0LTk3": {
    "descriptor": "aad.ZWUwODZlZTQtN2U3MC03M2U0LTk3",
    "directoryAlias": "John.Jumbo",
    "displayName": "John Jumbo",
    "domain": "78b2bd11",
    "legacyDescriptor": null,
    "mailAddress": "John.Jumbo@me.nz",
    "origin": "aad",
    "originId": "7c75ce3a-70a0-40e4",
    "principalName": "John.Jumbo@me.nz",
    "subjectKind": "user",
    "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/mbie-sandbox/_apis/Graph/Users/aad.ZWUwODZlZTQtN2U3MC03M2U0LTk3"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to filter on a dictionary, you can use [an object projection, with `*`](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#object-projections).
With this you are coming back to an array, that you can further filter [when the first projection has been stopped, with a pipe expression](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions).

This gives you the query:

```
* | [?subjectkind == 'group'].descriptor
```

That, on this example JSON:

```json
{
  "aad.some_gibberish_characters_group_1": {
    "descriptor": "aad.some_gibberish_characters_group_1",
    "subjectkind": "group"
  },
  "aad.some_gibberish_characters_user_1": {
    "descriptor": "aad.some_gibberish_characters_user_1",
    "subjectkind": "user"
  },
  "aad.some_gibberish_characters_group_2": {
    "descriptor": "aad.some_gibberish_characters_group_2",
    "subjectkind": "group"
  }
}
```

Would yield:

```json
[
  "aad.some_gibberish_characters_group_1",
  "aad.some_gibberish_characters_group_2"
]
```

Comment: The Key value pairs are case sensitive. Once I used the SubjectKind from the code, it works like a charms. Thanks